# "HttpContext.Current.Session" vs Global.asax "this.Session"

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, global-asax

Recently, while working on some code for an ASP.NET project at work. We needed a tracking util to take basic metrics on user activity (page hit count etc) we would track them in [`Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx), then save the data to DB via `Session_End` in [`Global.asax`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2.aspx).

I began hacking away, the initial code worked fine, updating the DB on each page load. I wanted to remove this DB hit on each request though and just rely on `Session_End` to store all the data.

All of the tracking code is encapsulated in the `Tracker` class, including properties that essentially wrap the Session variables.

**The problem**  is that when I executed `Tracker.Log()` in the `Session_End` method, the [`HttpContext.Current.Session`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) in the Tracker code was failing with a [`NullReferenceException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx). Now, this makes sense since [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) always relates to the **current** request, and of course in `Session_End`, there is no request.

I know that `Global.asax` has a `Session` property which returns a `HttpSessionState` that actually seems to work fine (I ended up injecting it in to the tracker)..

**But I am curious, how the hell can I get the same reference to the `HttpSessionState` object used by `Global.asax` from *outside* of `Global.asax`?**

Thanks in advance guys, I appreciate the input. :)

Comment: Another note is that Session_End is also not guarenteed to be called.  This is the case for SQL Session and out-of-state session setups.

Comment: Can some one kindly put a code snippet for this question's answer for beginners to understand. How to access in "in Proc" mode the values stored in current.session somnwhere in the application and then access it in global.asax file. Can I simply use `this.session` in `session_end` or some additional code is required?

Comment: Also, if multiple users are logged in to the site. then `this` will individually refer to each request right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Global.asax implements HttpApplication - which is what you are talking to when you call **this** from within it.

The MSDN documentation for [HttpApplication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) has details on how you can get hold of it in an HttpHandler for example, and then get access to the various properties on it.

**HOWEVER**

Your application can create multiple instances of HttpApplication to handle parallel requests, and these instances can be re-used, so just picking it up somehow isn't going to guarentee that you have the right one.

I too would also add a note of caution - if your application crashes, there's no guarentee that session_end is going to be called, and you'll have lost all the data across all sessions, clearly not a good thing.

I agree that logging on every page is probably not a great idea, but perhaps a halfway house with some asynchronous logging happening - you fire details off to a logging class, that every now and then logs the details you are after - still not 100% solid if the app crashes, but you're less likely to lose everything.

Comment: Great answer, helped scope things in my mind. Totally agree with the last paragraph as well. Thinking of setting up a sliding expiration on the tracker to log the info sooner than session timeout and without Session_End. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 18):

To answer the original question better:

### Background

Every single page request spins up a new `Session` object and then inflates it from your session store. To do this, it uses the cookie provided by the client or a special path construct (for cookieless sessions).  With this session identifier, it consults the session store and deserializes (this is why all providers but InProc need to be Serializable) the new session object.

In the case of the InProc provider, merely hands you the reference it stored in the `HttpCache` keyed by the session identifier. *This is why the InProc provider drops session state when the `AppDomain` is recycled (and also why multiple web servers cannot share InProc session state*.

This newly created and inflated object is stuck in the `Context.Items` collection so that it's available for the duration of the request.

Any changes you make to the `Session` object are then persisted at the end of the request to the session store by serializing (or the case of InProc, the `HttpCache` entry is updated).

Since `Session_End` fires without a current request in-fly, the `Session` object is spun up ex-nilo, with no information available. If using InProc session state, the expiration of the `HttpCache` triggers a callback event into your `Session_End` event, so the session entry is available, but is still a copy of what was last stored in the `HttpContext.Cache`. This value is stored against the `HttpApplication.Session` property by an internal method (called `ProcessSpecialRequest`) where it is then available. Under all other cases, it internally comes from the `HttpContext.Current.Session` value.

### Your answer

Since the Session_End always fires against a null Context, you should ALWAYS use this.Session in that event and pass the HttpSessionState object down to your tracing code.  In all other contexts, it's perfectly fine to fetch from `HttpContext.Current.Session` and then pass into the tracing code. **Do NOT**, however, let the tracing code reach up for the session context.

### My answer

Don't use `Session_End` unless you know that the session store you are using supports `Session_End`, which it **does** if it returns `true` from `SetItemExpireCallback`. The only in-the-box store which does is the `InProcSessionState` store. It is possible to write a session store that does but the question of who will process the `Session_End` is kind of ambiguous if there are multiple servers.

Answer (score 4):

I think you already answered your own question: usually the Session property in Global.asax and HttpContext.Current.Session are the same (if there is a current request). But in the case of a session timeout, there is no active request and therefore you can't use HttpContext.Current.

If you want to access the session from the method called by Session_End, then pass it as a parameter. Create an overloaded version the Log() method, which takes a HttpSessionState as a parameter, then call Tracker.Log(this.Session) from the Session_End event handler.

BTW: you are aware that you can not rely on the session end event in any case? It will only work as long as you have the session state in-process. When using SQL server or StateServer to mange the session state, the session end event will not fire.

Comment: But my question is "how do I get a reference to the same object used by Global.asax"? :)

Answer (score 3):

The `Session_End` event is raised only when the `sessionstate mode` is set to `InProc` in the `Web.config` file. If session mode is set to `StateServer` or `SQLServer`, the event is not raised.

use `Session["SessionItemKey"]` to get the session value.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am in the same problem to track the session activity. Instead of using session_end event, I have implemented the IDisposable interface and destructor to my sessiontracker class. I have modified the Dispose() method to save the session activity to DB. I invoked the method obj.Dispose() when a user clicks the logout button. If user closed the browser by mistake, then GC will call the destructor while cleaning the objects (not immediately but for sure it will call this method after sometime). The destructor method internally execute the same Dispose() method to save the session activities into DB.

-Shan

Answer (score 0):

Session is available in your Global.asax file, during the Session_Start event. Maybe wait until this point to do stuff?

Answer (score -1):

Remember that Session_End runs when the session times out without activity. The browser doesn't originate that event (because it's inactive), so the only time you actually will get the event is when using the InProc provider.  In EVERY OTHER provider, this event will never fire.

Moral?  Don't use Session_End.

Comment: Fair point, but the question is obviously based on the assumption that we *are using Session_End (be it a good or bad choice)

Comment: So, telling someone that they are DOING IT WRONG, in a way THAT CAN FAIL SURPRISINGLY, is a bad answer? See "Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?" http://is.gd/gSb1

Comment: For the record, I totally agree with the main point of your post, but I personally feel it didn't contribute towards an "answer" to the question itself.. "Dont use" doesn't help IMHO.. "Dont use by try this" may have been a lot more useful.. :)